# In the ReportFolder metadata, what does the sharedTo reference when sharing to a User?

Tags: deployment, metadata, reports-folder, deployment-error

I'm trying to deploy a singular Report and Folder. When I deploy I get an error saying `The user, group or role is not associated with a valid group.` for the Folder. As a result my report fails as well saying it can't find the Folder.

The only thing I can think of is in this particular environment there are three user records that potentially represents me (I don't know why please don't ask). I have to think that the `<sharedTo>` is failing to find me, and that it is looking for a User record with an Email that matches.

If this is indeed the case then the value it would be looking for would match one of the records that represents me (and only one), which is indeed active.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>Manage</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>First.Last@Company.com</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>User</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>MyReportFolder</name>
</ReportFolder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharedTo references the User Name of the user rather than the Email address. If you're hitting this error in a non-production environment, then it's worth checking that there isn't a different suffix being added to the usernames within that environment.

Comment: If I understand correctly Salesforce will use `First.Last@Company.com` as in the SharedTo but also look for that to be suffixed with the sandbox environment name correct?  If that's the case then it is matching on the User record I don't want it to match to lol.

Comment: Yeah the sandbox environment would be added as the suffix. If that's the case then it sounds like you either need to update the metadata record before you do the deployment, or update the user records so that the one you do want used has the correct format.